# Shell script to list out the larger files in a dir recursively

Tags: bash, shell, find

Shell script to list out the files in a dir recursively which is huge. I am using:

```
 find <path> -mtime +20 -exec ls -ls {} \; | sort -n -r | head -100 | awk '{print $10}'
```

Issues:

- Slower execution
- I am not having read permissions inside few sub-directories

Is there any better way to achieve this?  I have tried:

```
du <path> | sort -n -r | head -n 100
```

Much faster but not that effective.

Comment: try also ls -R, but they would all use same system calls inside so should have comparable performance

Comment: `... ls -s ... awk '{print $2}'` might be a tiny bit more portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find  -size +k -atime + -printf "%s,\t%a,\t%p\n"|sort -nr

will give you the desired output

here the sike is on kb and the age is the last access time.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size distribution of the files your `find` is finding, you might consider using the `-size` predicate to weed out a lot of the smaller fish before the list gets dumped onto `sort`.  If this is something you run regularly, make a note when you start getting less than 100 lines out of `head` and use that as an indication that it's time to lower the size limit you're giving `find`.

Lack of permissions is not a problem you're going to be able to overcome without getting the permissions on the directories in question changed or escalating your privileges so you can read them.

Answer (score 1):

`du` is almost there, try

```
du -aS | sort -n -r | head -n 100
```

which only return you the large files excluding any directories

Comment: Could add -b or -k to du command for more human-readable sizes

Answer (score 1):

find has a handy -printf directive:

`find . -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 100`